# laravel passport revoke and prune event listener is not doing anything

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I've added this two event listeners to my : `EventServiceProvider`

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens',
    ],

    'Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens',
    ],
];
```

And in my AuthServiceProvider I have :

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
        passport::$revokeOtherTokens;
        passport::$pruneRevokedTokens;
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(1));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(2));

    }
```

I want passport to revoke all other user access tokens and then prune them if they are revoked. but nothing is happening and every time I request an access token from postman I get a new access Token while there are several access tokens in the database.

Comment: Did you create proper classes in your `app\Listeners`? These do not come out of box and you have to write them on your own.

Comment: @Skysplit Thanks for your tip. I've solved my problem you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've Solved My problem This way : 
Step1 - In `EventServiceProvider` should change the path to the Access Token created and also refresh token created :

```
 protected $listen = [
        'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
            'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens',
        ],

        'Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated' => [
            'App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens',
        ],
    ];
```

Step2- generate this two listeners events :

```
php artisan event:generate
```

Step3- Modify `AccessTokenCreated` & `RefreshTokenCreated` event handle methods :

RevokeOldTokens Class :

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use DB;

class RevokeOldTokens
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  AccessTokenCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AccessTokenCreated $event)
    {


        DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
            ->where('id', '<>', $event->tokenId)
            ->where('user_id', $event->userId)
            ->where('client_id', $event->clientId)
            ->update(['revoked' => true]);


    }
}
```

PruneOldTokens Class :

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use DB;

class PruneOldTokens
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  RefreshTokenCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(RefreshTokenCreated $event)
    {

        DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('id', '<>', $event->refreshTokenId)
            ->where('access_token_id', '<>', $event->accessTokenId)
            ->update(['revoked' => true]);

    }
}
```

After This steps if I send any request to my project it will check for tokens and if there is another token it will revoke it and make it unathorized.

Comment: Great!!! But when multiple user tries to login then all `oauth_refresh_tokens` revoked without last logged user `oauth_refresh_tokens`

I think this should be revoked only requested user's previous `oauth_refresh_tokens` tokens like as - `oauth_access_tokens`

Comment: yeah your right, but I managed to solve the problem, by removing these two listeners and writing logout method to delete and revoke the active token.

Answer (score 1):

May be because you missed something important to let the passport works find,

1- Register Passport service provider in the providers array of your config/app.php
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,

1- you have to add the Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens trait to your App\User model
2- in your config/auth.php configuration file, you should set the driver option of the api authentication guard to passport

check this
http://www.snippetcase.com/snippet/61/API+Authentication+(Passport)+Laravel+5.3

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same question !
I did the same and this too :

```
    $id = $request->user()->id ?? -1;
    $token = Token::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    foreach ($token as $t) {
        $tokenRepository = app(TokenRepository::class);
        $refreshTokenRepository = app(RefreshTokenRepository::class);

        if (isset($t)) {
            $tokenRepository->revokeAccessToken($t->id);
            $refreshTokenRepository->revokeRefreshTokensByAccessTokenId($t->id);
        }

        RefreshToken::where('access_token_id', $t->id)->delete();
        $t->delete();
    }
```

Comment: `if (isset($t)) {` you wouldn't be inside the `foreach` if `$t` wasn't set.

Comment: Also `user_id` can belong to many `client_id` for others dealing with many clients with shared users (e.g User A belongs to Organisation A, B & C)