# Laravel passport using an old access token

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm trying to move my application from a server to AWS using Laravel Forge services. but I have third party applications (Android APP) using API's to access data's in my application using Laravel passport. My Android APP is using a bearer (Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL.....) and it's working without issue on the old sever. But now when I'm trying to use that same using the same database and API it gives the "Unauthenticated" error. I have used the same user and I did even copied all the oauth tables that Laravel Passport uses and it was on the old server and I did change the APP_KEY to the old server too. I don't know how to solve it I've been trying to find some solution in the past two days but I got no luck.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758505/laravel-passport-revoke-and-prune-event-listener-is-not-doing-anything

Comment: @user6854465 Thanks but it's not same as my issue

Comment: do you run `php artisan passport:keys` in the server? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#deploying-passport